# perl report formatting using printf - skip over some lines.

Tags: perl, formatting, report

> I have a output that looks like this :

```
BEGIN newcomm stat for rufarm102
__________________________________________________________________________________

ibfarm102 localtick     Boston       hibmis100 procHKHD2  Hongkong   PidMonRsp
ibfarm102 localtick     London       stopsrv1 proceu8  Zug   PidMonRsp
ibfarm102 localtick     Greenwich       hibmis100 procHKHD2  Hongkong   PidMonReq
ibfarm102 localtick     New York      stopsrv1 proceu8  Zug   PidMonReq

END : ibfarm102  newcomstat
```

> and I run it through this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open (REPORT , "/home/data/report20110801130041");
while (<REPORT>){
  if ($_ =~ /BEGIN/){
     print $_ ;
  }
  if ($_ =~ /END/){
     print $_;
  }
  if ($_ =~ /OCOMsg2/){
     use Term::ANSIColor;
     print color 'red';
     ($config_host , $config_process, $config_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_host_region, $stat_message_class) = split(/\s+/, $_ );
     printf "%-15s %-10s %10s %15s %-10s %-8s %10s", $config_host , $config_process, $config_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_host_region, $stat_message_class ;
     print color 'reset';
     print "\n";
  }
  else{
  ($config_host, $config_process, $config_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_host_region, $stat_message_class) = split(/\s+/, $_ );
  printf "%-10s %-10s %10s %15s %-10s %-8s %10s", $config_host , $config_process, $config_region, $stat_host, $stat_process, $stat_host_region, $stat_message_class ;
  print "\n";
  }

}
```

> I make an effort to skip the BEGIN and END lines - but they get printed out twice - and 
>   i have tried skipping over the BEGIN and END a few times, a few different ways.  I dont 
>   need the BEGIN and END lines split and formatted by printf.

```
BEGIN newcomm stat for ibfarm102
BEGIN      newcomm          stat             for ibfarm102
```

---

```
ibfarm102  localtick   Greenwich       hibmis100 procHKHD2  Hongkong  PidMonRsp
ibfarm102  localtick   Greenwich        stopsrv1 proceu8    Zug       PidMonRsp
ibfarm102  localtick   Greenwich       hibmis100 procHKHD2  Hongkong  PidMonReq
ibfarm102  localtick   Greenwich        stopsrv1 proceu8    Zug       PidMonReq

END : ibfarm102  newcomstat
END        :           ibfarm102      newcomstat
```

Comment: I don't think you can split on whitespace, since then "New York" will not be printed properly. Looks more like fixed width data, which means either regex or pack/unpack. Possibly tab-delimited.

Answer (score 1):

Your second and third `if`s should be `elsif`; otherwise, the BEGIN and END print out once and then again in the else clause (since as is that else catches everything that isn't OCOMsg2).

Comment: yup that did the trick - i need to get to know the difference between if elsif.

Answer (score 1):

Add `next` into the blocks handling matching `BEGIN` and `END`:

```
while(<REPORT>) {
    if (/BEGIN/) {
        print;
        next;
    }
...
```

This will make it start the next iteration of the `while` loop.

Comment: This worked as well - i went in with(suggestiong  from previous comments)   the if elsif thing instead.